# NHibernate exception enumerator was modified

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I have a multithreaded NHibernate application with ThreadStaticSessionContext.
I bind un each thread a new session. Before exiting the thread I commit the transaction and i get

```
enumerator was modified

  at NHibernate.Util.SequencedHashMap.OrderedEnumerator.MoveNext()  
  at NHibernate.Util.IdentityMap.get_EntryList()  
  at NHibernate.Util.IdentityMap.ConcurrentEntries(IDictionary map)  
  at NHibernate.Event.Default.AbstractFlushingEventListener.PrepareEntityFlushes(IEventSource session)  
  at NHibernate.Event.Default.AbstractFlushingEventListener.FlushEverythingToExecutions(FlushEvent event)  
  at NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultFlushEventListener.OnFlush(FlushEvent event)  
  at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.Flush()  
  at NHibernate.Transaction.AdoTransaction.Commit()  
  at ...
```

I don't have a clue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This exception is usually thrown when you add/remove from a collection while it is being enumerated (like in a `foreach` statement).

Comment: The code fails in 

try
            {
                Transaction.Commit();
                Session.Close();
                return true;
            }
            catch( Exception ex )
            {
                //log ex
                Console.WriteLine( ex );
                Console.ReadKey();
                if( Transaction != null )
                    Transaction.Rollback();
                if( Session != null )
                    Session.Clear();
                return false;
            }

in Transaction.Commit()

Comment: It looks like the collection is being modified by another thread during the `Commit`